# NGINX return 410 for deleted CSS and JS files

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, nginx, http-status-code-410

I have a problem with a plugin I've deleted, apparently the cache on the users browser still send request for some JS and CSS files that are gone, the problem is that this is causing a lot of 404 errors in the logs (in 1 day I generated 4GB of error logs only containing the 404 deleted CSS and JS files).

I was trying to create a setting on NGINX that will send a 410 response to everyone that was trying to access the missing JS and CSS files, the path of the files is the same:

/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/js/autoptimize_single_32ab5663ad75c559c9af68098a1b63e6.js

/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/css/autoptimize_32c1c99d8f7a5a9618074737134c8f9c.css

I tried various location settings I found online for both all files that contains autoptimize_*.css and js and the folder /autoptimize, but it didn't work, it was like this:

`location ^~ /autoptimize { return 410; }`

What I'm missing?

Comment: Those files URIs doesn't start with `/autoptimize`, try `location ^~ /wp-content/cache/autoptimize/ { return 410; }` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
location ^~ /wp-content/cache/autoptimize/ { return 410; }
```